# Title bar buttons on both sides

Tags: window-manager, budgie

Some people like [title bar buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/273335/is-there-a-name-for-the-close-minimize-and-restore-buttons) on the right side and some on the left side. I can't decide.

Is there any way, that I could have them on both sides? (and see myself what side I would use)

This could also be useful for people who need to share their computer with people, who like the buttons on the other side.

Comment: https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues/1531

Answer (score 0):

Launch Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout close,minimize,maximize:minimize,maximize,close
```

This should work with GNOME desktop environment and its cousins.

For Budgie desktop environment run the following instead

```
gsettings set com.solus-project.budgie-wm button-layout close,minimize,maximize:minimize,maximize,close
```

Comment: No errors on running the command, but no effect after reboot.

Comment: 'close,minimize,maximize:minimize,maximize,close' , same in dconf

Comment: Budgie settings shows still left. https://i.imgur.com/GTnnfx5.png

Comment: @RasmusKallas What's the output of `gsettings get com.solus-project.budgie-wm button-layout`?

Comment: 'close,minimize,maximize:appmenu' So changing that to close,minimize,maximize:appmenu:minimize,maximize,close'?

Comment: @RasmusKallas Yes, try that and report please (sorry, I didn't notice you were using Budgie).

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work.. It gets chagned back. https://i.imgur.com/5FviMaE.png Maybe it is the button-style messing with it?

Comment: So probably reporting this to https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues

Comment: @RasmusKallas Sorry, currently I don't have a Budgie setup to test the settings :( Reporting to GitHub sounds like a good idea!

Comment: Broken on Fedora, seems like a Gnome issue.